# Explicit densities for Brownian motion hitting times

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm looking for functions $g: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the hitting time

$$\tau := \inf \{t \geq 0 : B_t \nleq g(t) \} $$

has an explicit density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. What are possible examples?

The case where, for some $R> 0$, $g(t) \equiv R$ is constant leads to the hitting time having Lévy distribution. Indeed for $g(t) = R - \alpha t$, we also obtain an explicit density of 
$$\rho_{\tau}(t) = \frac{R}{\sqrt{4\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{(R - \alpha t)^2}{4t}}$$

Are there other functions out there where a similar representation exists?
Is there an explicit density for, say, $\inf \{t \geq 0 : B_t \nleq M_t \}$ for some process $M_t$ with $M_0 > 0$.

Comment: The difference between two Brownian motions is a Brownian motion, so your last question is a special case of your first $g(t) \equiv R$.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, of course. I'll change the question to a more general wording, but that's very helpful, I'm not sure how I did not think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See e.g. [ANALYTIC CROSSING PROBABILITIES FOR CERTAIN
BARRIERS BY BROWNIAN MOTION](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.2826.pdf), especially Example 2 (page 9) there for a square-root barrier, Example 3 (page 9) there for a square-root-times-log-factor barrier, and further references therein.